# Convert 3D plane of image into 2D image to be used as texture in blender

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, perspective, blender

I'd like to take a section of the flooring (a section with no furniture on it) from the image below which has a perspective and convert it to a 2D image which I can then use as a texture file in a 3D modelling application such as blender. I don't want to take a single tile from the manufacturer's website as I'm trying to maintain the variability that will exist in reality from tile to tile.

I'm wondering whether I can use the `Perspective Warp` tool in Photoshop or another other feature of Photoshop or any other program to achieve this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Would be *lightyears* easier to simply find a flat image of a marble floor. Even for a very experienced user, that's a project taking many, many hours. Especially considering the lighting in that photo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you propose would work well. Transforming the tiles for perspective will blur the pixels and degrade the image quality. Also you'd need to fix the lighting. Sounds like far too much work to be honest.

Instead, if you have one good 2D tile image, start with that.

Duplicate the tile layer several times, rotate them randomly. Enable the transparent pixel lock, then use the Clone Stamp, and the Dodge and Burn tools to make variations.

For example, this was just one tile originally, and here I have made another three variations.

[image]

Comment: Photoshops perspective crop does exactly this. But it won’t remove the highlights and shadows etc… so expect plenty of clean up.

Comment: A perspective crop won't work well for this. My answer explains why it won't work. I'm suggesting another method completely.